# Turn more complex SQL query to Eloquent Query (Models)

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I try to convert my PHP/JS application into a laravel project, however I am pretty new to Laravel and the Eloquent relationships.

So far I have created an **User** model with the following functions, describing the db relationships as eloquent relationships:

```
public function configs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Configuration', 'user_id');
}

public function rooms() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Room','App\Configuration','user_id','config_id','id','id');
}
```

And a `Room` model with relationships:

```
public function configs() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Configuration', 'config_id');
}

public function user() {
    return $this->hasOneThrough('App\Configuration', 'App\User', 'user_id','config_id','id','id');
}
```

The `Configuration.php` is not filled with any eloquent relationships yet.

To my question: I want to get all rooms with their `config_id` for the requesting user. This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM rooms
INNER JOIN configurations ON rooms.config_id = configurations.id
INNER JOIN users ON  configurations.user_id = users.id
WHERE user_id = 4
ORDER BY config_id
```

I also have red the documentation, but things still won't get into my head if I have to make a more "complex" query like the above.

My attempts look like so:

```
$user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$projects = Room::with('Confuguration')
->whereHas('configs', function($q) use ($user_id){
      $q->where('config_id', 'like', $user_id);
})->get();

return view('home', compact('projects'));
```

Comment: Please clarify some more. What is the result of your attempt, and what do you want more?

Comment: @shoek - SSsorry for some missing Informations:
I want to get all config_ids with the rooms added to them for the current user.

Comment: I don't understand how you failed and what you want to improve. You got an exception? Always got an empty result? Want a `INNER JOIN` result but got a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` results? So far, OMR's answer looks good to me. If you have another problem, please make a comment.

Answer (score 0):

you wants all config_ids with the rooms added to them for the current user.

the room model already has a column name 'config_id' so no need for configs table 
info ...

in Room model we have a relation called 'user' (should be users with 's') we can use it combined with [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)

```
$projects = Room::whereHas('user', function($q) use ($user_id){
      $q->where('id', '=', $user_id);
})->get();
```

like i said, project now will be the rooms for user include 'config_id' so no need for loading 'configs' relation